# My post route doesn't work, postman thinks it is GET request

Tags: laravel, post, routes, get

I have my resource Route, it works fine for GET, but it doesn't work for post method

```
Route::resource('cart', CartController::class);
```

I have tried clearing the cache but it didn't solve.

a screenshot from postman:

GET request:

[image: GET request]

Post request:

[image: Post request]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, but I didn't actually know the real reason behind it.

Maybe it is because I remove the valet link and make another one, something related to the caching although I cleared all the cache before.

thank you all for your help

Answer (score -1):

Verb     URI     Action  Route  Name

GET /photos index   photos.index

GET /photos/create  create  photos.create

POST    /photos store   photos.store

GET /photos/{photo} show    photos.show

GET /photos/{photo}/edit    edit    photos.edit

PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo} update  photos.update

DELETE  /photos/{photo} destroy photos.destroy

make sure your url is in this format

Comment: add a screenshot of your postman request

Comment: Those should all be handled by it being a `resource` route

Comment: I have added the screen shots. and as @boombeer said, there handled automatically by the resource route.

Comment: add photo of your controller